# Convert UTC to CST time zone in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

[image: convert date & time into CST time-zone]
I want to convert given date & time into CST time-zone any formulae or script which i should use and i also want to convert it into IST time-zone..

Answer (score 2):

This should work for UTC->CST (UTC -06:00) in either [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) or [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets).

```
=A1-TIME(6, 0, 0)
```

For UTC->IST (UTC +05:30) use,

```
=A1+TIME(5, 30, 0)
```

Note that one subtracts and one adds. You cannot generate negative time with the TIME function.

Comment: I didn't want to downvote this because it does provide a useful solution (and the requester did not mention Daylight Savings Time [DST]), but it is not complete because it does not account for the possibility for DST. So depending on the destination time zone and the UTC date being converted, this formula could produce incorrect values. Unfortunately I am not aware of any functions in Google Sheets (or Excel) that can accurately calculate the destination date/time due to the complexities of time zones and DST.